# how to retrieve checkbox value from database in php using explode

Tags: php, html

I have created one form in that ii have put three checkbox out of three in some form some people have checked all subject and some have selected only two subject and i want to retrieve checkbox value from database. I have given my current code.If anyone know solution than please tell

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$db = mysql_select_db("db_new", $connection);
echo "Roll No:-$rollno\n";
echo "Name is:-$name\n";
echo "Division:-$division\n";
echo "Std:-$std\n";
echo "Gender:-$gender\n";
echo "Subject:-$subject\n";
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student_info where id=17");
$row= mysql_fetch_row($query);
$rollno = $row[1];
$name = $row[2];
$division= $row[3];
$std = $row[4];
$gender = $row[5];
$subject=mysql_query("select * from student_info where id=17");
while($fetch=mysql_fetch_object($subject))
{
    $r=$fetch->subject;
    $i=explode(",",$r);
    echo $i[0]."</br>";
    echo $i[1]."</br>";
    echo $i[2]."</br>";
}
mysql_close($connection);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Edit Form</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery%20validate/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery%20validate/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
    <script src="form.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="editform" method="GET">
    <div>
        <h1>Form</h1>
        <label><b>Roll No:</b></label>
        <input id="rollno" name="rollno" type="text" value="<?php echo $rollno ?>"> <br><br>
        <label><b>Name:</b></label>
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo $name ?>"> <br><br>
        <label><b>Division:</b></label>
        <select id="division">
            <option value=" " <?php if (!empty($division) && $division == '' )  echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>--select--</option>
            <option value="A" <?php if (!empty($division) && $division == 'A')  echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>A</option>
            <option value="B" <?php if (!empty($division) && $division == 'B')  echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>B</option>
            <option value="C" <?php if (!empty($division) && $division == 'C')  echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>C</option>
            <option value="D" <?php if (!empty($division) && $division == 'D')  echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>D</option>
        </select><br><br>
        <label><b>Std:</b></label>
        <input id="std" name="std" type="text" value="<?php echo $std ?>"><br><br>
        <label><b>Gender:</b></label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" <?php if($gender=='male'){ echo "checked=checked";}?>>Male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" <?php if($gender=='female'){ echo "checked=checked";}?>>Female<br><br>
        <label><b>Subject:</b></label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="box[]" class="subject" value="maths" <?php echo "checked";?>>maths<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="box[]" class="subject" value="science" <?php echo "checked";?>>science<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="box[]" class="subject" value="english" <?php echo "checked";?>>english<br>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is the data from the DB actually stored? How do you want it expressed? Why are you using `mysql` functions when you should be using at least `mysqli` but preferably `PDO`?

Comment: SHOW YOUR $r VALUE HERE

Comment: Please. First of all please use PDO or mysqli - and also don't save comma-seperated values in one datafield. You can do an extra table and join it or something. But making querys with comma-seperated values is sometimes pretty annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
 $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
 $db = mysql_select_db("db_new", $connection);

 $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student_info where id=17");
 $row= mysql_fetch_row($query);
 $rollno = $row[1];
 $name = $row[2];
 $division= $row[3];
 $std = $row[4];
 $gender = $row[5];
 $subject=mysql_query("select * from student_info where id=17");
 while($fetch=mysql_fetch_object($subject))
 {
   $r=$fetch->subject;
   $i=explode(",",$r);

 }
 mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

Inside the checkbox you can check by using in_array

```
    <label><b>Subject:</b></label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="box[]" class="subject" value="maths" <?php if (in_array("maths", $i)){  echo "checked";}?>>maths<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="box[]" class="subject" value="science" <?php if (in_array("science", $i)){  echo "checked";}?>>science<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="box[]" class="subject" value="english" <?php if (in_array("english", $i)){  echo "checked";}?>>english<br>
```